# Ionic/Angular Auth from ASP.net Membership DB

Tags: asp.net, angular, authentication, ionic3, asp.net-membership

Im looking to create an Angular 4 app or possibly an Ionic app. The problem i face is im a bit unsure how to implement the authentication. i currenctly have an asp.net webforms site that uses the asp.net membership db. i would like to make use of this, but cant seem to find any relevant information on it. if anybody can shed any light on this or point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Web API to your .NET solution, which then utilizes the same business logic (including Authentication logic) you are using with your web forms. These APIs can then be consumed by your Angular/Ionic app via http and/or rxjs.

Comment: yeah i have an api thats built using service stack. but im just not sure how to implement it. the membership uses an auth cookie, right? i can use the membership provider to auth the user at a given endpoint but im really not too sure what to do after that. what do i send back to the user to use in future requests. i know the normal approach to this is to use an auth token. do i need to create an auth token after authenticating using membership at the endpoint?

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. It is good to use auth token with APIs due to their nature of use by any http device.